# How to cross reference tables from select()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing a list of categories which I want to select everything from. I have another table containing categories that the specific user has selected.

I want to select all of the current categories available and then add a new row in the query result called selected if the user has selected that category already.

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT category.*
     , user_category.user_cat_id AS 'selected' 
  FROM category
  JOIN user_category
    ON category.cat_id = user_category.category
    WHERE user_category.user_id = 1
```

This seems to only bring out the categories that have been selected, rather than them all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I have tried to use a LEFT and RIGHT join and neither work. The query is returning only the categories the user has currently selected. I would like the query to return all of the categories but add an extra row called selected if the user has selected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would do this by moving the condition on the user to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT c.* ,
       (CASE WHEN uc.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as selected'
FROM category c LEFT JOIN
     user_category uc
     ON c.cat_id = uc.category AND uc.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: I see! So the `LEFT JOIN` focuses on taking everything from the `category` table but joins the `user_category` table onto the `SELECT`, if the `user_id` does not exist for that category, it still loads the category but adds `selected` as 0... this is perfect! Thank-you Gordon!

Comment: @KDOT . . . Exactly.  The `LEFT JOIN` keeps everything in the first table.  Non-matches in the second table (based on the `ON` condition) have `NULL` columns from that table.

Comment: Cheers for that, Gordon! It makes sense now, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `WHERE` clause is removing all the rows where the user hasn't selected something in that category. Try changing your query to this:

```
SELECT category.* , IFNULL(user_category.user_cat_id, 0) AS 'selected' 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN user_category 
  ON category.cat_id = user_category.category 
WHERE user_category.user_id = 1 OR user_category.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This will not do what the OP expects when *another* user has selected the category, but the given user has not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right. Schoolboy error! The `ON` clause is indeed the right place for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

By joining the two tables, you only get the rows for which the join criterion exists in both tables. Say you have [A, B, C, D] in table "category" and [A, C] in table "user_category", joining them on cat.id only gets you rows that contain [A, C].

Use a normal query to get all active categories, and IF EXISTS to get the selected categories.

Comment: I have looked into IF EXISTS prior to asking however, I can't seem to generate a new row in the output, 'selected', if it does or doesn't exist. Any solutions?